# Apache Artemis queue monitoring with Zabbix

Tags: jmx, zabbix, activemq-artemis

I'd like to keep track of data that might be stuck in Apache Artemis queues and I'd like to leverage its JMX management abilities together with our Zabbix instance.

What steps do I need to take in order to successfully connect Zabbix to Artemis via JMX? The ones mentioned in https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management.html are not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable the internal connector and go the other way around by adding this to the `artemis.profile` file:

```
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099"
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1098"
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=edimq-broker-master-az1.dc01.clouedi.local"
```

However, this way it's anything but secure, I know.

Comment: This is not the recommended approach. Can you elaborate as to why the approach outlined in the documentation didn't work for you?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. JConsole does not share much about the reasons for failure and so does Zabbix (I don't have access to the logs though). All I learned was that connection could not be established.

Comment: Have you looked at the "jmx" example we ship at examples/features/standard/jmx?  It demonstrates how this all works.  A programmatic client connects via JMX to the remote broker and executes some management methods.

Comment: I must admit I only went through it and didn't go deeper. I might try to compile the example and connect to the broker tomorrow to (maybe) get better info about the cause.

Comment: You just need to run `mvn verify` to build and run the example. It will create a broker instance, start the broker, and run the client all automatically. After the example runs you can go to into the `target/server0` directory and look at all the configuration files. You can start broker independently of the example if you wish. You should be able to connect to it with JConsole no problem (I can).

Comment: There must be something wrong with my configuration then. I haven't had enough time to investigate yet but the example worked well. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I discovered that the example worked because it run on machine with the firewall turned off. The problem is that there are two ports that need to be opened on the firewall and one of them - the RMI server port - is not known in advance.

Comment: I further learned that the RMI port configuration has been somewhat forgotten in the current Artemis version but I could fix that easily. I'll try to publish patch during tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management.html#configuring-remote-jmx-access) states, you need to add this to your `management.xml`:

```
<connector connector-port="1099"/>
```

This will expose a JMX connector on `localhost` so if you want to be able to access it remotely from another machine on your network (i.e. your Zabbix instance) then you should do something like:

```
<connector connector-port="1099" connector-host="myhost" />
```

Also, if you have multiple IP addresses on the machine hosting the broker you'll want to set this system property in the `JAVA_ARGS` variable in `artemis.profile`:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myhost
```

Then point your Zabbix instance at the broker using a url like:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://myhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

You can see this in action by running the `jmx` example shipped with Artemis in the `examples/features/standard/` directory. Just navigate into that directory and run `mvn verify`. Running the example will create a broker instance, start the broker instance, and run the client all automatically. After the example runs you can go to into the `target/server0` directory and look at all the configuration files to compare them to your own. You can also start broker independently of the example if you wish (by running `./artemis run` from the `target/server0/bin` directory). Once the broker is running you should be able to connect to it with JConsole no problem using a JMX url like this:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Comment: Did you receive any errors? What was the behavior? Just saying that it "didn't work" isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: I understand. No errors other than "connection timed out" stuff.